# Why is SDRAM speed independent from the motherboard?

Tags: clock, ram

My understanding based on my research says that Synchronous DRAM has its name because it synchronises with a clock on the motherboard. How is it, then, that the speed of the RAM doesn't depend on the motherboard, and a 2133 MHz stick of RAM is 2133 MHz regardless of the motherboard you connect it to? I would think that if the RAM is synced to a clock speed on the motherboard, then doubling that speed would also double the RAM frequency. Is it just that motherboards all use a standard clock speed, or am I missing something?

Comment: The clock comes from the CPU, not the motherboard. And yes, all 2133 MHz clocks have the same frequency :-)

Comment: Like any other kind of "rating", whatever labeled on the memory is just a maximum and you can run ran a range of frequencies below that. To directly answer your question, because the memory controller is (now usually) on the CPU so the memory's operating condition depends on the CPU's capability and its settings.

Comment: The ram can only reliably go so fast as it was manufactured to go ('overclocking' is essentially a bet that this is not true) - modern ram modules come with a serial eeprom that tells the CPU how fast the ram can reliably go - essentially the CPU makes the clock speed that the rams ask for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Synchronous DRAM has its name not because it is works synchronously with some motherboard clock. It outputs/receives data synchronously with the clock supplied by MEMORY INTERFACE. And the interface clock is supplied by MEMORY CONTROLLER, which is a part of CPU nowadays (or used to be in North Bridge).

The clock architecture of modern PCs is quite complicated. In simplified terms, mainboard supplies some baseline, relatively low-frequency clock. This clock goes to CPU, which uses a bunch of programmable PLLs to generate internal clocks for all internal interfaces and interconnect fabric, including a separate MEMORY CONTROLLER block. The memory controller, in turn, uses this internal clock to drive DRAM interface. This clock is configurable, and BIOS can accommodate almost any memory grade using information from DIMMs. Many internal sections of CPU can run on different clock domains, and reliable crossing of data is provided by use of synchronizing FIFOs.

Answer (score 2):

On modern CPUs the memory is somewhat asynchronous to the CPU.  So the CPU runs at its own best clock, and the memory runs at its best clock (well, spec anyway).  Desynchronizing them allows best performance from each.  A far cry from the Atari days when a 2 MHz processor ran at 1.79 to stay in lock with the NTSC color clock.

Why isn't the CPU perpetually waiting for memory? The CPU has its own local instruction cache.  There is also significant logic in the CPU to "look ahead" and anticipate which memory locations are likely to be needed next.  And of course the next shoe to drop was attempts at pre-execution... This sort of look-ahead is related to the Spectre and Meltdown bugs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just that motherboards all use a standard clock speed, or am I missing something?

There is a small EEPROM [chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) on the memory stick which the computer reads at boot. This contains information about the RAM type, size, frequency, timings, etc. The BIOS then configures the cpu's memory controller accordingly.

As mentioned in the other answers, CPU and RAM run asynchronously so they can use different frequencies. The CPU can also lower frequency to save power. RAM clock speed isn't linked to CPU clock.